# If $a\equiv b \pmod{p_i}$ for $i=1,2,...,k$ then prove $a\equiv b \pmod{p_1p_2\cdots p_k}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a\equiv b \pmod{p_i}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,k$ then prove $a\equiv b \pmod{ p_1p_2\cdots p_k}$

$a\equiv b \pmod{p_1}$ implies $a-b=p_1x_1$
Similarly, $a-b=p_2x_2,\ \cdots,\ a-b=p_kx_k$

So,
$$(a-b)^k = p_1p_2...p_kx$$ where $x=x_1x_2...x_k$

I'm stuck here, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $p_i$ divides $(a-b)^k$, since $p_i$ is prime, $p_i$ divides $(a-b)$ or $(a-b)^{k-1}$ recursively you obtain $p_i$ divides $(a-b)$ thus $p_1...p_k$ divides $a-b$ since $p_i$ is prime.

Here I use that if $p,q$ divide $u$ and $gcd(p,q)=1$ then $pq$ divide $u$. To see this, write $u=cp=dq, ap+bq=1$, thus $u=apu+bqu=apdq+bqcp=pq(ad+bc)$.